# Open Windows Phone ApplicationBar from code-behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, code-behind

Is there an official way or trick to open the Windows Phone ApplicationBar using C# from the code-behind? I'd like to show my users additional options hidden in the menu.

To be clear, I don't need to create the menu in code-behind (but can, if that helps in any way).

Comment: Do you mean creating the Bar or expanding it to show menuitems?

Comment: I mean expanding it to show the menu items.

Comment: For now it's like Jaihind wrote in his answer - There is no way to open app bar programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no way to open application bar programmatically. But you can create application bar in C#. Here is the sample.

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
    ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0; 
    ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
    ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;

    ApplicationBarIconButton button1 = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
    button1.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/YourImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
    button1.Text = "button 1";
    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(button1);

    ApplicationBarMenuItem menuItem1 = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
    menuItem1.Text = "menu item 1";
    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(menuItem1);
```